# PropertyGrid customizing font property

Tags: c#, propertygrid

Im using a property grid to display some properties. I want the user to be able to choose a font but not to choose the size. I added a font property like this to my class encapsulating all the metadata for the property grid:

```
public class DetailFilterProperties : CollectionBase, ICustomTypeDescriptor
{
    public DetailFilterProperties(TreeViewEventArgs e) {...}

    [CategoryAttribute("Base"), DescriptionAttribute("The font"), ReadOnly(true)]
    public Font Font
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Now can anybody please tell me how to enable only 8pt size to make sure the user cannot change the size in the fonts dialog?

thanks for your help.

Edit:

I changed my program a little and i think im almost there. Please have a look...

I added a class for my Font Editor:

```
public class ETFontEditor : UITypeEditor
{
    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal;
    }

    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {
        FontDialog dlg = new FontDialog();
        dlg = new FontDialog();
        dlg.MaxSize = 8;
        dlg.MinSize = 8;

        Font font = value as Font;
        if (font != null) {
            dlg.Font = font;
        }

        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            return dlg.Font;

        return base.EditValue(context, provider, value);
    }
}
```

then I added a new Converter class:

```
public class ETFontConverter : TypeConverter
{       
    public ETFontConverter()
    {

    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        return new ETFontEditor();
    }
}
```

which will return an instance of my font editor. And last i added a method to my Property Descriptor class:

```
public override TypeConverter Converter
    {
        get
        {
            var key = _key;
            if (key.ToString() == "Font") {
                return new ETFontConverter(this);
            }
            return base.Converter;
        }
    }
```

which will return a new font converter if the font property is set.

The problem is the program wont call the EditValue method of my FontEditor so its always showing the font dialog with more options than just 8pt for size available when i click the ellipse button. And also the property grid is displaying the name of the property (Font) then a blank space(where the name of the font should be) and then the ellipse button. Does anyone know how to fix these two problems?

thank you

Comment: You're confusing converter & editor. Please post a repro if you really need help

Answer (score 2):

You could define a custom [UITypeEditor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.drawing.design.uitypeeditor.aspx) that redefine the font chooser dialog and set a max and min size, like this:

```
  [CategoryAttribute("Base"), DescriptionAttribute("The font")]
  [Editor(typeof(MyFontEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
  public Font Font
  {
      get;
      set;
  }

  ...

  public class MyFontEditor : UITypeEditor
  {
      public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
      {
          return UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal;
      }

      public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
      {
          FontDialog dlg = new FontDialog();
          dlg = new FontDialog();
          dlg.MaxSize = 8;
          dlg.MinSize = 8;

          Font font = value as Font;
          if (font != null)
          {
              dlg.Font = font;
          }

          if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
              return dlg.Font;

          return base.EditValue(context, provider, value);
      }
  }
```

This is what the use will see if he tries to enter another size:

[image]

Comment: I added a new class for my Font Editor and also changed the attribute for my property like you suggested, but its still showing the old (ms) fonts dialog. Debugging the program i notices its not jumping into the constructor of my new font editor. Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the "old ms fonts dialog"? I should work fine, or post a repro code.

Comment: Its displaying the fonts dialog it displayed before: The one where the user is able to select a font size > 8pt. It might be problem I'm using a Property Descriptor to display the data.

Comment: Ah, ok, that's probably that. Try to remove your custom type desciptor, and you'll see it work.

Answer (score 0):

you can build a custom property grid. however i've not used property grid till now. you can have a reference from below link might be helpful for you.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22717/Using-PropertyGrid

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jO8Yfi_843I

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx

Comment: i built a custom property grid. I just want to make sure the user cannot change the size property in the fonts dialog within my property grid.

Comment: you can mark it as readonly.    [ReadOnly(true)]

    public string ObjectAttribute1

    {

        get { return this.objectAttribute1; }

        set { this.objectAttribute1 = value; }

    }

Comment: but then i wouldnt have a fonts dialog anymore, right? I mean the property grid would display two rows with a string value with one beeing readonly.